# owl carousel stops after switching tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Hi i'm experimenting with the auto play function in owl carousel, however whenever i switch to another web tab in chrome and come back to my webpage with the carousel, it stops working unless i give it a drag on the image. Here's my html and jquery code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head lang="en">
      <title>MySite</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.carousel.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.theme.default.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div> <img src="1.jpg"></div>
        <div> <img src="2.jpg"></div>
        <div> <img src="3.jpg"></div>
        <div> <img src="4.jpg"></div>
        <div> <img src="5.jpg"></div>
        <div> <img src="6.jpg"></div>
      </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var owl = $(".owl-carousel")
      owl.owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:3000,
        autoplayHoverPause:false
      });

      owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[5000]);
    });
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: i hve the save issue using version 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [ifvisible.js](https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js)

And try to use both .blur and .focus commands otherwise it won't work

This is implementation for my site

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){

var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:2000,
    dots:false,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2 
        },
        620:{
            items:3
        },
        992:{
            items:4
        },
        1200:{
            items:6
        }
        }
        })
jQuery('.owl-carousel .owl-item').on('mouseenter',function(e){
    jQuery(this).closest('.owl-carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
})
jQuery('.owl-carousel .owl-item').on('mouseleave',function(e){
    jQuery(this).closest('.owl-carousel').trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[2000]);
})
    ifvisible.blur(function(){

        owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay',[2000]);

    });

    ifvisible.focus(function(){

        owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[2000]);});
    });

});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer

```
$(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

    if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
        switch (e.type) {
            case "blur":
                // do work
                owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
                break;
            case "focus":
                // do work
                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000]);
                break;
        }
    }

    $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
});
```

try this it will work ENJOY :D

Answer (score 0):

You can simply trigger the next slide button. It worked well for me:

```
$(window).on('focus', function () {
    $('.owl-next').trigger('click');
});
```